# Tkinter - Generate checkboxes from list of tuples

Tags: python, tkinter

Given a list of tuples, I need to create a checkbox for each tuple with a variable assigned to it. My problem is the list of tuples is variable length and I haven't been able to figure out how to do the variable assignment on the checkboxes in `tkinter`.

For instance, my raw list of tuples would be:

```
[('GigabitEthernet0/0/0', '1.1.1.1'), ('GigabitEthernet0/0/1', '2.2.2.2'), 
 ('GigabitEthernet0/0/2', '3.3.3.3'), ('Loopback0', '4.4.4.4')]
```

Here's a section of the code I have. It isn't complete but you can see what I'm working with. This section gets the information I need to work with and simply is putting it on display as checkboxes.

```
output = net_connect.send_command('show ip int brief')
regex_active_interfaces = re.compile(r'(\S+)(?:\s+|\t+)(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\s')
active_interfaces = regex_active_interfaces.findall(output)
for i in active_interfaces:
    ipEntryText = Checkbutton(debuggerWindow, text=i)
    ipEntryText.pack()
```

I need a check box for each of these that could be then be referenced by a command to determine which of these interfaces has been selected.

Comment: Extend with `ipEntryText._variable = tk.IntVar()  ; .configure(variable=ipEntryText._variable)`. Checked => `<checkbutton ref>._variable.get() == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a dictionary to hold the variables like below:

```
cbvars = {}
for i in active_interfaces:
    var = StringVar(value=0)
    btn = Checkbutton(debuggerWindow, text=i, variable=var, anchor='w')
    btn.pack(fill='x')
    cbvars[i] = var
```

Then you can use the dictionary to check which checkbutton is checked:

```
for interface, var in cbvars.items():
    print(interface, var.get())
```